# Does kafka-connect support transactions?

Tags: transactions, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I need to write a client which will insert events into kafka .I need to insert Multiple events into multiple topics within single transaction .I want to know if it is possible through kafka-connector or should i create a new producer in java for the same which will begin and commit transaction .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible in Connect, please see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6080